# How to populate server called data to materialized css chip autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I am trying to populate materialized css chip autocomplete data by using a server call. I did tried many ways to make it, but not able to do so. Sample that i have tried to make it work as below:

```
var storeData;
$(document).on('keyup', '#inputid', function() {
    storeData = //do server call and return data;
});

$('.chips-autocomplete').material_chip(
{autocompleteOptions : storeData}
});
```

Like above code i tried many different combinations. need help to make the server call and populate dynamic data as chip.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re?rq=1